# Why does my For...Each statement complete in its entirety?

Tags: excel, vba

When the following code runs, it doesn't complete in its entirety. I usually have to run it a few more times to ensure all the data in that range has been inspected and the row deleted if it meets my criteria.

```
Const A% = 1
Const B% = 2
Const C% = 3
Const D% = 4

'Some code

If myCL <> "" Then
    For Each Cell In RngB.Cells
        If Cell.Value <= myBal Then
            r = Cell.Row
            If ws.Cells(r, D) <= myScore And ws.Cells(r, C) Like myCL Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
ElseIf myCL = "" Then
    For Each Cell In RngB.Cells
        If Cell.Value <= myBal Then
            r = Cell.Row
            If ws.Cells(r, D) <= myScore Then
                Cell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End If
```

I understand that I should loop through a range in reverse when using something like `For i = ## to 1 Step -1`, but I don't believe this would apply in this situation.

My issue is that when `Cell` should meet the criteria, it sometimes skips over it, which I then rerun the code and it will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method is, instead of adding the rows to an array, or looping backwards and deleting the rows one by one, is to define a `DelRng` as a `Range` object.

Everytime, you pass your criteria, than you add that `Row` to the `DelRng` object, using the `Union` function, and at the end, you delete `DelRng` with one-shot.

**Code**

```
Dim DelRng As Range  ' new range object, collects all rows that needs to be deleted

If myCL <> "" Then
    For Each Cell In RngB.Cells
        If Cell.Value <= myBal Then
            r = Cell.Row
            If ws.Cells(r, D) <= myScore And ws.Cells(r, C) Like myCL Then
                ' add current row to DelRng
                If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(r))
                Else
                    Set DelRng = .Rows(r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
ElseIf myCL = "" Then
    For Each Cell In RngB.Cells
        If Cell.Value <= myBal Then
            r = Cell.Row
            If ws.Cells(r, D) <= myScore Then
                ' add current row to DelRng
                If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Rows(r))
                Else
                    Set DelRng = .Rows(r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End If

' now delete the entire rows at once (will save you a lot of run-time)
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.Delete
```

Comment: This will work fine if there aren't too many rows to delete; `Union`'s performance degrades geometrically when called in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're pulling the rug under the `For Each` statement by deleting the row it is iterating on (`For Each` scans left to right, from the top row to the bottom row). Excel is nice enough to resume the iteration at "next" cell, which really is located on the row after the one it just deleted, and typically 1 cell to the right. But then, your code missed all of the leftmost cells on the new current row, some of which may fulfill your criteria.

**Edit**

The issue can be circumvented by somehow taking note of the rows to delete, without deleting them within the `For Each` loop. My personal favorite way of doing so is to use a `Scripting.Dictionary`, as demonstrated below:

```
Sub ForEachWithRowDeleteDemo()
    Dim rangeOfInterest As Excel.Range
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim dicRowIndexesToDelete As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rowIndex As Variant

    Set rangeOfInterest = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z10") 'ASSUMPTION: rangeOfInterest is a contiguous range; no checks are made here.
    Set dicRowIndexesToDelete = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In rangeOfInterest.Cells
        If cell.Value2 = 123 Then '...your conditions go here.
            'Cumulate distinct row indexes.
            dicRowIndexesToDelete(cell.Row - rangeOfInterest.Row + 1) = True
        End If
    Next

    If dicRowIndexesToDelete.Count > 0 Then
        If rangeOfInterest.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            'Exceptional case: rangeOfInterest is a single cell.
            rangeOfInterest.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            'Mark each of the range's rows.
            rangeOfInterest.Clear
            For Each rowIndex In dicRowIndexesToDelete.Keys
                rangeOfInterest.Cells(rowIndex, 1) = True
            Next

            'Find the marks and delete the entire rows.
            rangeOfInterest.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If

    Set dicRowIndexesToDelete = Nothing
    Set cell = Nothing
    Set rangeOfInterest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Notice that all rows are deleted at once, for better performance. This will only work if there are no more than 8'192 separate "islands" of rows to delete; beyond that, the `SpecialCells` method would fail. The exceptional case of a single cell range of interest must be handled separately, since `SpecialCells` will consider the whole worksheet as its search zone if applied to a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof of concept that should work around the problem you're facing. Instead of deleting the rows in your `For Loops`, you could assign the `Row` to a 1-dimensional `Array`, then build a string and delete the rows all at once outside of your `Loop`.

**Run this on a sheet with the first 7 rows filled out, then hit play and watch.**

```
Sub DeletingRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim myArr(0 To 2) As Long
    Dim myStr As String

    myArr(0) = 2
    myArr(1) = 4
    myArr(2) = 6

    For Each myRow In myArr
        myStr = myStr & myRow & ":" & myRow & ","
    Next myRow

    myStr = Left(myStr, Len(myStr) - 1)

    ws.Range(myStr).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

---

**How to integrate this into your code**

Where `x` is a long starting at 0.

```
If myCL <> "" Then
    For Each Cell In RngB.Cells
        If Cell.Value <= myBal Then
            r = Cell.Row
            If ws.Cells(r, D) <= myScore And ws.Cells(r, C) Like myCL Then
                myArr(x) = Cell.Row
                x = x + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
ElseIf myCL = "" Then
    For Each Cell In RngB.Cells
        If Cell.Value <= myBal Then
            r = Cell.Row
            If ws.Cells(r, D) <= myScore Then
                myArr(x) = Cell.Row
                x = x + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End If
For Each myRow In myArr
    myStr = myStr & myRow & ":" & myRow & ","
Next myRow

myStr = Left(myStr, Len(myStr) - 1)

ws.Range(myStr).Delete
```